# Difference between text inside the span vs just inside the body

Tags: html

What's the difference between a text inside the span vs not inside the span (just inside the body)

Because technically, they have different width, is it possible to make them the same in width?

The one outside the span has 24 x 17

[image]

The one inside the span has 22.22 x 17

[image]

I'm also curios why they are different?

Physically, they are the same. What's the right explanation for this?

Comment: Your curiosity is really dangerous. What is the point?

Comment: Haha.. just curios though, how html renders the texts

Answer (score 3):

The text inside body are text nodes which represent the whitespace characters between your tags in the DOM ([Text Nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text))

So the "text" outside span shows you the width as per your code formatting, spacing or indentation in your code.

Another difference between the two is that parent of text node "text" is diplay block; whereas text inside span has its display as inline.